# strrev() function can't be used even after including string.h in Ubuntu 20.04, compiler gcc 9.3.0. What can I do?

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-20.04, string.h

I am unable to use strrev() function even after including string.h in Ubuntu 20.04. Compiler says undefined reference to strrev(), but strlen() and other functions work. What should I do?

Comment: Don't forget to use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger, or [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the behavior of programs on Linux

Comment: The profile of Anurag Pathak is mentioning C++; my comment was based on that public profile (which does *not* mention C)

Comment: `strrev()` is not a C standard library function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement it yourself.

```
char *strrev(char *str)
{
    char *end, *wrk = str;
    {
        if(str && *str)
        {
            end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
            while(end > wrk)
            {
                char temp;

                temp = *wrk;
                *wrk++ = *end;
                *end-- = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```